# RStudio keeps jumping out garbled warning message

Tags: r, rstudio

I'm new to RStudio. There is one problem bothering me for weeks as the screenshots below. The warning message keeps jumping out at any time when I'm using RStudio. Often, I just click the OK and RStudio continue working fine. However, the frequency of the warning is getting higher and that stops me from typing any script more or saving file...

The version I installed is Traditional Chinese and I have set the encoding to UTF-8. Can anyone give me a favor?

[image: error message]

Comment: `1.` always install english versions in the programming world! `2.` Try installing english version and see if you get the error. `3.` If  you still get an Error report to RSTUDIO.

Comment: Since this is is really a bug report for Rstudio specifically, you should report it at https://community.rstudio.com/. This is not really a general programming question that Stack Overflow would be good for.

Comment: @MrFlick This question looks OK to me. The help page [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) specifically allows "software tools commonly used by programmers". I think that RStudio should qualify.

Comment: @G5W I think there's a big difference between an IDE bug report and a general question about using an IDE for some sort of programming task. This feels like a question only the developers of Rstudio can help with rather than any other programmer. I didn't vote as off-topic but really just tried to point the OP to a place they are more likely to get the help they need.

Comment: What version of R do you have installed? Did you install the official CRAN build of R for Windows, or a different build?

Answer (score 0):

I was having this same annoying message. I was putting all my files in a Google Drive folder, and after disconnect the drive, the message stopped appearing.